# If statement that increases variable for each line when conditions not met in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to ask for some advice. I have a .csv file that I used to calculate the difference in time between two sightings(Elapsed). I would like to label every sighting(Elapsed) that is below 30 as visit number 1 but once the condition is false(above 30), it has to increase the visit number permanently to two....

Data table looks as follows:

`Species    Elapsed VisitNo
aardvark     5 
aardvark     10
aardvark     2 
aardvark     30 
aardvark     4 
aardvark     30 
aardvark     10`

what I want is something like:

`Species    Elapsed VisitNo
aardvark     5        1
aardvark     10       1
aardvark     2        1
aardvark     30       2
aardvark     4        2
aardvark     30       3
aardvark     10       3`

`TempVisit <- 1
VisitNo = TempVisit <- ifelse(Elapsed < 30 ,1,TempVisit + 1))`

Although this only increases the value where the statement is false and not the following line as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df$VistiNo <- cumsum(df$Elapsed >= 30) + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cumsum`.

```
df$VistiNo <- cumsum(df$Elapsed >= 30) + 1
df
#   Species Elapsed VistiNo
#1 aardvark       5       1
#2 aardvark      10       1
#3 aardvark       2       1
#4 aardvark      30       2
#5 aardvark       4       2
#6 aardvark      30       3
#7 aardvark      10       3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "aardvark", class = "factor"), Elapsed = c(5L, 
10L, 2L, 30L, 4L, 30L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```